# fine uploader 3.4 and setParams

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader with jquery plugin.
Need to pass params dynamically before uploading files, so, the setParams() method should do the job. I can't have an exception on the onSubmit call back :

1) the uploader declaration

```
 function initUploader() {
         var up = $('#BSUploader').fineUploader({
                      multiple: true,
                      debug: true,
                      request: {
                          endpoint: '${request.contextPath}/quantum/uploadToS3',
                          //params: {'folderId':r }
                      },
                      dragAndDrop: {
                          extraDropzones:[$('#filesContainer')],
```

...

2) onSubmit callback

```
...
}).on('submit', function(event, id, name) {
          var r = $("#curfolderid").val();
          alert(r);
          up.setParams({'folderId':r});
```

3) error log

```
[FineUploader] Caught exception in 'onSubmit' callback - Object [object Object] has no method 'setParams' bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:4
qq.log bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:4
qq.FineUploaderBasic.log bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:26
b bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:47
a._options.callbacks.(anonymous function) bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:47
qq.FineUploaderBasic._upload bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:43
qq.FineUploaderBasic._uploadFileOrBlobDataList bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:43
qq.FineUploaderBasic.addFiles bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:29
qq.DragAndDrop.callbacks.dropProcessing bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:69
b bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:51
qq.UploadDropZone.onDrop bundle-bundle_uploader_defer.js:52
(anonymous function)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using the jQuery plug-in wrapper correctly.  The [documentation on this plugin](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/modes/using-jquery-plugin.html) clearly explains how to call API methods when using the plug-in.  You should really follow the readme starting from [the first page](http://docs.fineuploader.com), and then follow the path outlined based on your intended use.  Doing so will prevent you from running into problems that would have been solved by familiarizing yourself with the library.

Now, on to fixing your problem...

The `up` variable you've created is assigned a `jQuery` object representing the element with an ID of "BSUploader".  You are attempting to call a function that does not exist on this jQuery object.  Fine Uploader does not pollute the jQuery object with additional methods.  All accepted/recommended standards outlined on the jQuery website were followed when developing the plug-in wrapper.  This means that you must invoke API methods within the context of the plug-in instance.

So, you must change this line:
`up.setParams({'folderId':r});`

to this:
`up.fineUploader('setParams', {'folderId':r});`

Another option is to eliminate the `up` variable entirely.  You really don't need it, as you can call `setParams` in your callback handlers like this:
`$(this).fineUploader('setParams', {'folderId':r});`

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the support. i'm converting basic uploader  to the JQuery plugin and cleaning up the code right now. Cheers.